# Popup menu in Android 1.5

Tags: android, popupmenu

I need something that looks like a popup menu in Android 1.5 that I can trigger from a button press.
(the version number is a hard limit, by the way)

According to the documentation, an ordinary popup menu is supported, but only in Android 3.x and higher.

I'd prefer to do it without adding another Activity, but can if that's the best option.

I already have the menu defined in XML, I just need to figure out how to make it display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `Dialog`. I recommend you to use `AlertDialog`, as it is easier to use through its Builder class. You will be able to use your custom XML to define the layout for the Dialog.

It is available since API level 1, so you would not have problems. Here you have doc info [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: Is there any way to add more than three items to an AlertDialog?

Comment: Of course, you can use `setView()` to set your custom Layout with the elements you need. Also, you can call `findViewById()` on the `AlertDialog` instance so you can then manage them. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want that pop up menu to display more options, I suggest using the `QuickAction`. It is not available in Android SDK so you're gonna have to build it manually

```
          //Add action item
 ActionItem addAction = new ActionItem();

   addAction.setTitle("Add");
   addAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add));

//Accept action item
 ActionItem accAction = new ActionItem();

 accAction.setTitle("Accept");  
  accAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_accept));

 //Upload action item
 ActionItem upAction = new ActionItem();

 upAction.setTitle("Upload");
 upAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_up));
```

Looks like this

[image]

More information on how to implement it is  available [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)